# Java and WebSphere MQ server integration

Tags: java, jms, websphere, message-queue

I am using IBM Websphere MQ of v7.5.0.6 which is installed on Linux 3.10.0-1160.90.1.0.1.el7.x86_64. I have created the required queue manager and channel.

I need to send a message to a queue hosted on WebSphere MQ, and I am using `com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory`. Below is the code I have written to create a connection factory. I have added the Maven dependency for IBM MQ as below. When I am trying to deploy this code on WebLogic I am getting below error.

```java
@Bean
public MQConnectionFactory connectionFactoryMQ() {
    MQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQConnectionFactory();
    try {
//      connectionFactory.setTransportType(CommonConstants.RTT_CP_TCP);
        connectionFactory.setHostName(hostName);
        connectionFactory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(portNumber));
        connectionFactory.setQueueManager(mqChannelManager);
        connectionFactory.setChannel(mqChannel);
        connectionFactory.setStringProperty(JmsConstants.USERID,"ABC123");
        connectionFactory.setStringProperty(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_FORMAT, "MQSTR");
        connectionFactory.setIntProperty(JmsConstants.JMS_IBM_MSGTYPE, CommonConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        log.error("*****Error While creating connection factory object****** : {}", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return connectionFactory;
}
```

Dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
    <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQComponent and com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment
```

I have added the code above.

Comment: You are using a very old version of MQ. Suggest a more up-to-date version would be more appropriate

Comment: Any other alternative you could suggest. Rather than upgrading the version, if I could use a compatible version of spring boot mq

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem, but read about stash file here - https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=interoperability-gskit-version-compatibility

Comment: If you are running on WebLogic you should use MQ as JMS provider and access it via JNDI and JMS APIs not directly using MQ classes.